# Binary search tree insertion in Racket

Tags: tree, lisp, scheme, racket

I am learning Racket and implemented a BST insert function `(insert tree n)` where the format for a BST node is `(left-tree value right-tree)`.

**Example**

'((() 2 ()) 3 ()) is isomorphic to:

```
      (3)
  (2)    ()
()  ()
```

Therefore `(insert '((() 2 ()) 3 ()) 4)` yields `((() 2 ()) 3 (() 4 ()))`:

```
      (3)
  (2)    (4)
()  ()  () ()
```

**Implementation**

My implementation feels overly complicated.  For example, I used `append` with `cons` so that the right-tree for 3, represented by `()`, would properly become `(() 4 ())` after inserting 4.

How can I approach this problem more elegantly or more functionally?

```
#lang racket

(define (left tree)
  (list-ref tree 0)
  )
(define (value tree)
  (list-ref tree 1)
  )
(define (right tree)
  (list-ref tree 2)
  )
(define (merge left value right)
  (append (cons left '()) (append (cons value '()) (cons right '())))
  )
(define (insert tree n)
  (cond
    [(empty? tree) (append '(()) (cons n '()) '(()))] ; leaf
    [(> (value tree) n) (merge (insert (left tree) n) (value tree)(right tree))] ; internal - go left
    [(< (value tree) n) (merge (left tree) (value tree) (insert (right tree) n))] ; internal - go right
    [(eq? (value tree) n) tree] ; internal - n already in tree
    )
  )
```

**Update**

Given the answer to the question, I updated my code:

```
(define (insert BST n)
  (cond
    [(empty? BST) ; leaf
     (list empty n empty)]
    [(< n (cadr BST)) ; internal - go left
     (list (insert (car BST) n) (cadr BST) (caddr BST))] 
    [(> n (cadr BST)) ; internal - go right
     (list (car BST) (cadr BST) (insert (caddr BST) n))] 
    [else 
     BST] 
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suspected, you don't need `append` for this problem. The trick is to notice that if, for example, your goal is to create the list `'(1 2 3)`, then writing `(list 1 2 3)` is more straight-forward and more efficient than writing `(append '(1) '(2) '(3))`.

With that in mind, consider the following insertion function:

```
(define (insert BST n)
  (cond
    ((null? BST)
     (list empty n empty))
    ((< n (cadr BST))
     (list (insert (car BST) n) (cadr BST) (caddr BST)))
    ((> n (cadr BST))
     (list (car BST) (cadr BST) (insert (caddr BST) n)))
    (else BST)))
```

To run a small test, suppose you have the list `'((() 3 ()) 5 (() 8 (() 10 ())))`, which looks as follows:
[image]

then inserting `7` to it, ie. `(insert '((() 3 ()) 5 (() 8 (() 10 ()))) 7)` will produce `'((() 3 ()) 5 ((() 7 ()) 8 (() 10 ())))`, which looks as follows:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!